# как в js получить ссылку с помощью data=“”

Tags: javascript

**как в js получить ссылку с помощью data=“”**

в моём случае в скрипте есть аналог для получении основной ссылке

url: iUrl, ->>> href="'+iUrl+'"

а в html data-url="{$link$}"

так мне нужно в тот же js использовать дополнительную ссылку в html data-trailer_url="{$trailer-link$}"

а в js trailer_url: trUrl, ->>> href="'+trUrl+'"

Вот кусок из js ... там где ссылка /trailers/

можете помочь реализовать я ноль в js

```
$('body').on('click','.js-trl',function(){
        var iUrl = $(this).data('url'), iThis = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: iUrl,
            beforeSend: function() {},           
            success: function(data) {
                $('body').append('<div class="tr"></div><div class="box"><div class="video-box"></div></div>');
                $(".video").append($('#trailer', data).html());
                $(".box").append('<div class="icon-left"><a href="'+iUrl+'" class="btn"><span class="play-circle"></span>Смотреть онлайн</a></div>');
                $(".box").prepend('<div class=""><div class="">Трейлер</div><span class="times"></span></div>');
                $(".box, .overlay").fadeIn('200');
                if (iThis.hasClass("have-trailers")) {
                   $(".tr-btm").append('<a href="/trailers/" class="btn"><span class="open-o"></span>трейлеры</a>');
                };
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Как я понял - вы хотите вытянуть ссылку, а вот откуда - что-то не понятно

Comment: с странице  html с data('url')

Comment: Чему равно iUrl в вашем контексте?

Comment: YA NOLI V JS 

VOT 

 var iUrl = $(this).data('url'), iThis = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: iUrl,

Comment: если вывести после присвоения так: `console.log(iUrl );` что выведется в консоли